# Use @aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming with react-native and expo-av to transcribe audios

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, expo-av, aws-sdk-js-v3

I am currently using **expo** with **react-native** and I am facing some difficulties in implementing the usage of **@aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming**.

I saw an implementation with **'react-native-live-audio-stream'** but since I am using **'expo'**, I thought **'expo-av'** would be a better approach because **'react-native-sound'** causes some issues working with **'expo'**.

To start I implemented the client of **'@aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming'** in my 'client/transcribe-client.ts':

```js
import { TranscribeStreamingClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming';
import { REGION, credentials } from '../handler';

export const transcribeStreamingClient = new TranscribeStreamingClient({
    credentials,
    region: REGION
});
```

Then this is the example of using react-native-live-audio-stream I got, my 'transcribe.ts':

```js
import {
    StartMedicalStreamTranscriptionCommand,
    TranscribeStreamingClient
} from '@aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
import { NativeEventEmitter, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import LiveAudioStream from 'react-native-live-audio-stream';
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';
import { transcribeStreamingClient } from './client/transcribe-client';

class TranscribeController {
    private isStarted: boolean;

    private emitter;

    private audioPayloadStream: Buffer[];

    private audioStream: typeof LiveAudioStream;

    private transcribeStreamingClient: TranscribeStreamingClient;

    constructor() {
        this.isStarted = false;
        this.emitter = new NativeEventEmitter();
        this.audioPayloadStream = [];
        this.audioStream = LiveAudioStream;
        this.transcribeStreamingClient = transcribeStreamingClient;
    }

    async init() {
        await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO
        ]);
        this.audioStream.init({
            sampleRate: 44100,
            channels: 1,
            audioSource: 6,
            bitsPerSample: 16,
            bufferSize: 2048,
            wavFile: 'test.wav'
        });
        this.audioStream.start();
        this.audioStream.on('data', (data) => {
            this.audioPayloadStream.push(Buffer.from(data, 'base64'));
            if (!this.isStarted && this.audioPayloadStream.length !== 0) {
                this.start();
            }
        });
    }

    async start() {
        try {
            this.isStarted = true;
            const command = new StartMedicalStreamTranscriptionCommand({
                LanguageCode: 'en-US',
                MediaEncoding: 'pcm',
                Specialty: 'PRIMARYCARE',
                Type: 'DICTATION',
                MediaSampleRateHertz: 44100,
                AudioStream: this.audioGenerator()
            });
            const data = await this.transcribeStreamingClient.send(command);

            for await (const event of data.TranscriptResultStream!) {
                const results = event.TranscriptEvent?.Transcript?.Results;
                if (results && results.length > 0) {
                    const [result] = results;
                    const final = !result.IsPartial;
                    const alternatives = result.Alternatives;
                    if (alternatives && alternatives.length > 0) {
                        const [alternative] = alternatives;
                        const text = alternative.Transcript;
                        this.emitter.emit('recognized', { text, final });
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            if (this.isStarted) this.emitter.emit('error', true);
            this.stop();
        }
    }

    stop() {
        this.audioPayloadStream = [];
        this.audioStream.stop();
        this.transcribeStreamingClient.destroy();
        this.isStarted = false;
    }

    async *audioGenerator() {
        for await (const chunk of this.audioPayloadStream) {
            yield { AudioEvent: { AudioChunk: chunk } };
        }
    }
}

export const transcribeController = new TranscribeController();
```

And I tried to use in my component like this:

```js
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { styles } from './index';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
import { transcribeController } from '@/lib/aws/transcribe';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function TranscribeComponent() {
    useEffect(() => {
        Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
    }, []);

    const startTranscription = async () => {
        try {
            await transcribeController.init();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error initializing transcription:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button title="Transcribe Sound" onPress={startTranscription} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

So I just want to know how could I implement it so it transcribe the audio from a file or from microphone, this current code is not working.

This is the error I get when pressing the button:

```js
 LOG  [TypeError: Object is not async iterable]
 LOG  [TypeError: Object is not async iterable]
```

Dependencies for reference:

```
    yarn add @aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming aws-sdk react-native-get-random-values buffer react-native-url-polyfill react-native-live-audio-stream expo expo-av
```

Comment: in your code, either ```data.TranscriptResultStream``` or ```this.audioPayloadStream``` is not an iterable array/list that is why you are getting this error.

Comment: Yeah @RohitSK you're right
I just console.log(typeof data.TranscriptResultStream);
And got type: object 
That does not make sense to me since I am sending the StartStreamTranscriptionCommand it should return an iterable array/list right?

Comment: Hi, Hermes doesn't support async iterators yet (the feature is planned, but no release date yet), so for await is unsupported and produces the corresponding error message when encountered.

As you know, in RN apps JS code undergoes Babel transformations which should eliminate instances of for await.